# How do you restore playlists on an Apple Books app

Tags: books

My computer died and my backup service did not preserve the application settings but I did preserve the library folder in user/library, so I think I should be able to restore my Apple Books app to the same state I had it in before my computer keeled over.  I was using the app in an idiosynchratic way, I had all sort of folders and subfolders created for learning languages.  In effect, I turned the app into a language learning tool.  I'm aware of this file

~/Library/Containers/com.apple.BKAgentService/Data/Documents/iBooks/books.plist

But, one, I can't get the info in that file to populate in my app, two, I don't think it will do any good if I do because looking at the file with text edit, it seems to be not the right file since it only contains info for one book.

How do I find the file that determines the names of all the folders I had set up as well as the books I had created before my Mac keeled over?